# Fail to improve site first time loading performance

Tags: javascript, performance, webpack, bundling-and-minification, lighthouse

I am creating a site using HTML5, JavaScript and React.
I am using Google Chrome Lighthouse to check the performance of the site first load.

This is the Lighthouse Runtime environment:

- User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
- Device Emulation Nexus 5X: Enabled
- Network Throttling 562.5ms RTT, 1.4Mbps down, 0.7Mbps up: Enabled
- CPU Throttling 4x slowdown: Enabled

After many iteration and fixes these are the scores I have on Lighthouse so far:

- Performance 57
- Progressive Web App 100
- Accessibility 100
- Best Practices 88
- SEO 100

The best Practices is not at 100 because:

- the host I have does not provide HTTP/2 (I might change if that's really an issue)
- I have Google Ads script with has document.write() (can't change anything about that)

My big problem is with the Performance Metrics.
I have a white blank screen for more than 3.3s and the is fully showing after 8.3s!
The First meaningful paint is at 5,750ms, the first Interactive is at 6,720ms (same for Consistent Interactive)
The Perceptual Speed Index is 4,228 (score 64)
And the Estimated Input Latency is 16ms (score 100)

This is the Critical Chain Request:
[image: Critical Chain Request]

This is the Network overview:
[image: Network overview]

This is what I have done/tried so far:

- Moved all components in the start page to async load using react-code-splitting
- Optimized the images to use the new J2P, JXR and WEBP format, and made them the correct size so the browser does not have to resize them.
- Moved the content of App.js into index.js (before the loading would get index.js and vendor.js in parallel, then a js file with all the css files inside and app.js, and after that it would load in parallel the components that are used inside app.js
- Moved some css import to the components they are associated with.
- Used webpack-bundle-analyzer to try to find common libraries and how they are splitted. As you can see in the following screenshot there are a lot of duplicated modules in my bundles that I cannot find how to extract for efficiency. (lodash, react-overlays,...)

[image: Bundles]

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ChunkManifestPlugin = require('chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackChunkHash = require('webpack-chunk-hash');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
//var SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin = require('sw-precache-webpack-plugin');
const OfflinePlugin = require('offline-plugin');

// To handle the regeneratorRuntime exception
require('babel-polyfill');

require('file-loader');
require('css-loader');
require('style-loader');
require('html-webpack-template');

/* Shared Dev & Production */

const config = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  entry: {
    index: [
        // To handle the regeneratorRuntime exception
        'babel-polyfill',
        './index.js'
    ],
    vendor: ['offline-plugin/runtime', 'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-redux', 'history', 'react-router-dom', 'redux', 'react-router-redux', 'redux-form', 'lodash'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|otf|jp2|jxr|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /\/favicon.ico$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
              name: '[path][name][hash].[ext]',
              publicPath: '/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/style'),
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: '[name].[ext]' },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.xml/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: { name: '[name].[ext]' },
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
  },

  plugins: [
    // New moment.js optimization
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: 2
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      appMountId: 'app-root',
      inlineManifestWebpackName: 'webpackManifest',
      template: 'templateIndex.html',
      title: 'Our Site',
    }),

    new OfflinePlugin({
      AppCache: false,
      ServiceWorker: { events: true },
    }),

    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({analyzerMode: 'static'}),
  ],

  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
};

//if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
config.output.filename = '[name].[chunkhash].js';
config.plugins = [
  ...config.plugins,
  new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
  new WebpackChunkHash(),
  /*new ChunkManifestPlugin({
    filename: 'chunk-manifest.json',
    manifestVariable: 'webpackManifest',
    inlineManifest: true,
  }),*/
];
//}

module.exports = config;
```

my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      { "modules": false }
    ],
    "react",
    "stage-0",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [ "syntax-dynamic-import", "transform-react-jsx", "transform-decorators-legacy" ]
}
```

And my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import {Redirect, Route, Switch, withRouter} from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Async from 'react-code-splitting';

const TopBar = () => (<Async load={import('./containers/TopBar/TopBarAsync')} />);
const NavBar = () => (<Async load={import('./containers/NavBar/NavBarAsync')} />);
const BottomBar = () => (<Async load={import('./containers/BottomBar/BottomBarAsync')} />);
const UserHelpers = (props) => <Async load={import('./containers/UserHelpers')} componentProps={props} />
const Main = () => (<Async load={import('./containers/Main')} />);
const Blog = () => (<Async load={import('./containers/Blog')} />);
const PublicPage = () => (<Async load={import('./containers/PublicPage')} />);

import configureStore from './store/store';
const store = configureStore();

import './styles/font-awesome.min.css';

import './styles/app.css';
import './styles/TeamBrowser.css';

let googleTracking = null;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production') {
  // https://web-design-weekly.com/2016/07/08/adding-google-analytics-react-application/
  ReactGA.initialize([my key here]);
  googleTracking = function fireTracking() {
    let page=window.location.pathname+window.location.search;
    ReactGA.set({ page: page });
    ReactGA.pageview(page);
  }

  const runtime=require('offline-plugin/runtime');
  runtime.install({
    onUpdateReady() {
      runtime.applyUpdate();
    },
    onUpdated() {
      window.location.reload();
    },
  });
}

render((
  <Provider
    store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter
      onUpdate={googleTracking}>
      <div className="body">
        <header>
          <TopBar/>
          <NavBar />
        </header>
        <main>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
            <Route path="/main" component={Main} />
            <Route path="/Feed" component={Blog} />
            <Route path="/Blog" component={Blog} />
            <Route path="/:id" component={PublicPage} />
           <Redirect to="/" />
          </Switch>
        </main>
        <footer
          className="footer">
          <BottomBar />
        </footer>
        <UserHelpers />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>),
  document.getElementById('app'));
```

Right now I am out of ideas about how to improve the loading speed to get a better Lighthouse score.
Can anyone spot anything that I do not know about?

To me it looks like chunk-manifest-webpack-plugin is not doing its job properly because it is not extracting all the common modules.
And second, the index.[hash].js bundle contains files that it should not (ex: utils.js, files under the 'actions' folder,... These are my own files, but they are not referenced in my index.js so why does it put them there?

Comment: Blue and green colours mean "waiting" and "content download" respectively. Could it be that your server is just slow to serve up these files? Or your network connection?

Comment: I have a 100GB connection. But Lighthouse throttles the connection to test for 3G. I am updating the post with the Lighthouse settings.
Beside that does not change the fact that the bundles have duplicated content.